# getting the first letter of each word from sentences java and printing it out to the user from a file in java

Tags: java, cpu-word, sentence

Hello I am a beginner in java. I need to print the first letter of each word in a sentence from a text file and printing it out into a text file. However, I keep getting this error message 
Input

The input contains many test cases: 
 The first line contains an integer N that indicates the number of test cases. Each test case consists of a single line containing from 1 to 50 characters, that can be lowercase letters (‘a’-‘z’) or spaces (‘ ’). Watch out for leading and trailing spaces!

Output

**For each test case print the text that is hidden in the input.**

This is my error

```
   "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at main.main(main.java:23)"
```

and this is my code

```
public class main {     

        public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
            //reading from to the stream of lines 
            System.setIn(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream ("txt")));
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out"))));

            //Triming the space at the start of the sentence
            Scanner file = new Scanner(System.in);

            // read the lines of text 
            while ( file.hasNextLine() ){
            // Read the number of cases 
            //  if ( file.hasNextInt() ){
                    // number of cases 
                    int t = file.nextInt();
                    //looping through to number 4 
                    while (t-- > 0){
                        //for (int i=0; i>t; i++){

                        String input =file.next();

                        String b= input.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");

                        String[] sentence =b.split(" ");

                        for (int i1=0; i1<sentence.length;i1++ ){

                            String s = sentence[i1]; 
                            System.out.print(s.charAt(0));

                        } 

                    }   
            }
            System.out.close();
        }

    }
```

I appreciate your help ,

Comment: don't use nextInt to read your input, that is for when you expect only numbers. I recommend using nextLine() then parsing the lines you get back

Comment: I would also advise against changing the input and output with System. You shouldn't need to do that to read in and write to a file.